# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'" in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed Python 3.8.5 and I'm trying to run this code in Visual Studio Code:

```py
from lxml import etree
```

I run it on the terminal with:

```
python test.py
```

I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'

Here is the test in terminal and how I check the environment and location of lxml:

[image: test in terminal with: python test.py]

It seems nothing is wrong.

Comment: How about `python -m pip show lxml`?

Comment: **It shows this:**  
_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip_  
**Then I upgrade pip:**  
`(Python_torch) liheqian@liheqiandembp lesson % pip install --upgrade pip`  
**And I try again:**  
`(Python_torch) liheqian@liheqiandembp lesson % python -m pip show lxml`  
**It shows the same error:**  
_/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip_

Comment: I don't use conda/anaconda, but it seems like the `python` inside your virtual environment, the one you used to run test.py, is Python 2.7, and is *not* the same Python 3.8 where you have pip and where you installed lxml. I suggest recreating the virtual environment. Or maybe you have a `python3` that refers to Python 3.8.

Comment: Activate your virtual environment, then check `which python` and `python -V`. If it isn't Python 3.8, then something's probably wrong with your python env. Generally, on macOS, `python` usually means the system Python 2.7. Then, depending on how you installed Python 3, there's usually `python3`. Then, normally when you create a virtual env, `python` and `python3` becomes the same, and refers to your Python 3 installation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sincerely. Finally, I figure out what's wrong.It's all about environment varible! I solve this problem by adding a path to bash profile.

Comment: Cool. You might want to post that as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), with details of how you debugged the problem and how you eventually fixed it. It might help someone in the future.

Comment: OK~Be happy to~

Comment: It would help me if you could post your solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you have python3 installed (which can be verified by doing `python -V` or `python --version`), then you can try below.

```
python3 test.py
```

Comment: While that *could* work, I think the bigger problem is why the OP's `Python_torch` virtual environment `python` is not same as the Python 3 installation.